# ReactDOM render not working using CDN links

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Below is my html and index.js code. I can't seem to find the mistake as right now nothing is rendering on my html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: Do you see a successful network request for `index.js` in your dev tools? I do see a warning from React that [ReactDOM.render is deprecated](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis), but not sure if that's related.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `index.js` to this:

```js
import { createRoot } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1"
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<h1>Hello</h1>)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the babel standalone link as well for this to work.
Add this just above your `index.js` import in your html file:

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-kp7YHLxuJDJcOzStgd6vtpxr4ZU9kjn77e6dBsivSz+pUuAuMlE2UTdKB7jjsWT84qbS8kdCWHPETnP/ctrFsA=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
></script>
```